# LibGDX Making a single bullet kill only one enemy when enemies are overlapping

Tags: java, iterator, libgdx, collision, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm making a shooter with LibGDX. My code works when a single bullet hits a single enemy. When multiple enemies are stacked and the collision box of a bullet hits multiple enemy collision boxes, the game crashes with **Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1**

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this happens because the iterator tries to remove also as many objects from the bullet array as there were enemies killed in that collision, and while there's only one bullet for example killing three enemies the bullet array index goes below zero which causes the exception.

**My question is:** How can I modify the loop / code so, that one enemy dies with one bullet even though there are many enemies "stacked" and a bullet hits multiple enemies at once. Thank you.

```
bIter = bullets.iterator();
        while(bIter.hasNext()){
            b = bIter.next();           
            mIter = monsters.iterator();
            while(mIter.hasNext()){
                m = mIter.next();

                if(m.getBounds().overlaps(b.getBounds())){

                    mIter.remove();
                    bIter.remove();

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does adding a break help you? It will stop the loop as soon as one bullet hit an enemy. Both get removed (but only one enemy) and we start with the next bullet.

```
bIter = bullets.iterator();
while(bIter.hasNext()){
    b = bIter.next();           
    mIter = monsters.iterator();
    while(mIter.hasNext()){
        m = mIter.next();
        if(m.getBounds().overlaps(b.getBounds())){
            mIter.remove();
            bIter.remove();
            break; // <-- this is new
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well but Yes it does. Thanks again. I temporarily fixed it first with adding a small timer to the loop but this is more subtle and efficient solution by far.